# Add header and footer to each line in a file. Function returns only first line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem with some of my python code. I want it to open a file, with few lines of text, and add header + footer to each line in that file.
The problem is that 'create_output()' function returns only the first line with additional content. If I switch 'return' to 'print' at the end of this function it properly displays all lines from my file. What could be the reason? I want to understand what am I doing wrong here.

```
file_path = '/home/user/Desktop/text.txt'
file_path_edited = '/home/user/Desktop/text_new.txt'
header = 'http://'
footer = '.com'


def open_file():
    opened_file = open(file_path)
    return opened_file


def edit_file():
    edited_file = open(file_path_edited, 'w')
    return edited_file


def create_output():
    for line in open_file():
        line = line.strip()
        edited_line = header+line+footer
        to_file = edit_file()
        to_file.writelines(edited_line)
        to_file.close()
        return edited_line

print (create_output())
```

Comment: where is the 'create_content()' function?

Comment: Sorry, create_output() Eddited

Comment: Why do you have `return edited_line` in your `create_output()` loop?

Comment: Because the edited_line is the output? What should I return in ur opinion?

Comment: If you have [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) in the loop it will exit the function after the first iteration...

Comment: It does... However, if I return edited_line outside of this loop it just returns the last line.

Comment: Because you're changing `edited_line` in every loop iteration. If you want to store your strings for debugging purposes then you need to [append them to a list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Answer (score 0):

You get only one line, because you reopen the write-file all the time instead of letting it open, `"w"` will truncate the file on open - so last line lives, rest is useless IO. Also you never close your reader afaics.

> `open(filename, mode)` from https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files:
>   mode can be `'r'` when the file will only be read, `'w'` for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased), and `'a'` opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is automatically added to the end. `'r+'` opens the file for both reading and writing. The mode argument is optional; `'r'` will be assumed if it’s omitted.

Do not split the file open into extra functions, use `with open(...) as bla: bla.write(...)` so they get closed as soon as you leave the block or some exception happens.

Use string-formatting - either `'this {} ist repleaced with'.format("something")` or the inline variant - see below.

```
def create_output():
    modLines = []
    with open('/home/user/Desktop/text.txt',"r") as reader, \
         open('/home/user/Desktop/text_new.txt',"w") as writer: 
        for line in reader:
            line = line.strip().rstrip('\n') # rstrip might be better if you only cut \n
            modline = f'http://{line}.com'   # 3.6 inline string formatting, for 2.7 use 
            modLines.append(modline)         # 'http://{}.com'.format(line)

            writer.write(modline+"\n")       # write does not autoappend \n
    return modlines                          # return a list of written https...


print (create_output())
```

Should do the trick.

Links:

- [Format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)
- [Reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: Thx a lot! I rewrite it and now it works fine.
Well, more a lot more coding for me.

Comment: @OhDear Great. Read here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I changed it to something like this, now it works fine.
Thanks your feedback, now I know what I'm doing wrong.

```
file_path = '/home/user/Desktop/text.txt'
file_path_edited = '/home/user/Desktop/text_new.txt'
header = 'http://'
footer = '.com'



def CreateContent():
    with open(file_path) as read_file:
        with open(file_path_edited, 'w') as write_file:
            for line in read_file.readlines():
                new_line = "{}{}{}".format(header, line.strip(), footer)
                print(new_line)
                write_file.write("{}\n".format(new_line))


CreateContent()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could further improve your code as follows:

```
file_path = '/home/user/Desktop/text.txt'
file_path_edited = '/home/user/Desktop/text_new.txt'

header = 'http://'
footer = '.com'

def CreateContent():
    with open(file_path) as read_file, open(file_path_edited, 'w') as write_file:
        for line in read_file:
            write_file.write("{}{}{}\n".format(header, line.strip(), footer))

CreateContent()
```